# Techniques for working with a few large binary files in Git

Tags: git, version-control

I am working on a project using git, that has about 10 or 12 large binary files.

The files are essentially 3D models which will be brought together at the end of our project but during development we would like to keep them separate.

(This way each modeler can work on a specific model, and have previous versions of their model ignoring other people's work)

What is the best way to work on a project in this manner?  My concern is not the large file size of the models, my concern is how can there be a master repo that simply tracks each of the different models.

I would keep them separately entirely but different animators will be working on each of the models and so they need to be synced (they can't just be in separate repos) but I am not sure how to proceed.

Should I just use different branches for each model?

Comment: Git is notoriously bad for working with binary files.  Will you need to see diffs of the various files, or do you just need some pointers for how to create a repo in Git?

Comment: I know how to create the repo, and I have worked with git for a while (previously just with text files though). I do not need to really see the diffs, the commit log would be fine to see what changed (i.e. `added car to model`) but I do want to have a record of the versions of the binary files

Comment: "Should I just use different branches for each model?" Certainly not. That's not what branches are for, and you'll end up in trouble if you go down this path. If each model has its own modeler, what's wrong with putting all of your files together in the same repository and branch? Something like [`git-lfs`](https://git-lfs.github.com/), [`git-fat`](https://github.com/jedbrown/git-fat), or [`git-annex`](https://git-annex.branchable.com/) will help with file size.

Comment: I should have clarified, periodically different people will be working on the models.

Comment: Are you essentially trying to add file locking to Git, then? So you know that only one person is working on model at once?